# XAMPP, SQL and Xdebug

Tags: php, xdebug

First, I'm sorry for the double post, I deleted the previous one to make one more detailed, I'm a newbie of StackOverflow.

### Problem

I currently have an issue: I want to debug my PHP in VS Code but it is impossible I think without the line: `xdebug.start_with_request = Yes`. But when it is active my SQL became slow for an obscure reason.

I know it is strange but this make me crazy, and on my laptop I have EXACTLY the same issue. To make sure I've created a brand new folder for my XAMPP and the same issue appears again. Do you have any idea of what happen?

### My configuration on all of my computers:

- XAMPP
- VS Code
- Norton

### Details

This makes MySQL slow, and I don't have more configuration lines for Xdebug. Maybe I forgot something ?

```ini
zend_extension = xdebug
xdebug.mode = develop,debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll
```

This make my SQL work normally:

```ini
zend_extension = xdebug
xdebug.mode = develop,debug
xdebug_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll
```

### What I've tried already

1. Created a fresh install of XAMPP on my computer and Xdebug on XAMPP and copy paste my project inside
2. Change some lines on my configuration, delete the line `xdebug.start_with_request = Yes`
3. Try on another computer (my laptop)

### What I want

I would like to use debug mode and make MySQL work properly, and understand why this line make it slow.

If you need any other configuration feel free to ask.

Comment: As we already said, Xdebug doesn't directly affect sql. More likely your http request and php script is just generally slower because of the overhead of running a debugger. Have you got any real evidence that sql _specifically_ is slower, as opposed to just your script overall? And as we also said I believe, this is pretty normal and expected. There were some useful comments on that old question which are now gone, and we must start all over again. That is not a good use of anyone's time. It would be better to undelete the old one, and edit it if you have something new to tell us

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77366001/xdebug-makes-mysql-slow (for those who can view deleted posts)

Comment: For the second time, you have not provide insight into 'slow' .... xdebug slows down many operations, when there is a process listening ( a client debugger ).  I have seen up to 2x the execution time, but never a slow-down in MySQL commands (using PDO).  Atomically, my PDO `execute` run at the same speed with or without xdebug.  You could be chasing (wanting) the un-attainable.

Comment: I resolve my problem using xdebug.start_with_request = trigger and installing xdebug Helper extension on chrome :)